# I'm going to make a notepad using tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-datetime

```
def func_time() :
   with open ('filename.txt' ,'w') as File:
       time = datetime.now()
       time_string = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
       File.write(time_string)
```

If you press the Time/Date button like a Windows internal notepad, I want the current time and date to be written on the notepad.

Comment: Help me understand this... you want to create a button and anytime you click the button you want the current time to be written in a .txt file somewhere. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Whenever I click the time/date button, I want the current time and date to be written in the .txt file that I currently open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu item not added for `time/date`.

```py
editMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
mainMenu.add_cascade(label = "datetime", menu = editMenu)      # Item added
editMenu.add_command(label = "time/date", command = func_time)
```

The callback revised to insert datetime into the position of `INSERT`.

```py
def func_time() :
    time_string = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    st.insert(tk.INSERT, time_string)
```

Comment: Thanks to your help, I solved it right away. Thank you very much.